# com.vaadin.data.Provider not located

Tags: vaadin

Currently, I am working on a Vaadin web application project in Netbeans. Recently, I looked into using the ExpandingTextArea addon, which ended up running into an unfortunate compilation error.

Apparently, the Property class in `com.vaadin.data` was missing. After searching through my dependencies, I found the com.vaadin.data package in my vaadin-server `jar`, and as expected, property was missing.

https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.6/com/vaadin/data/Property.html indicated that Property has been present since version 3.0, and as the URL indicates, it's been present up to 7.7.6.

Unfortunately, I am using 8.4.2; looking at https://vaadin.com/framework/releases, no versions between 8.4.2 and 8.5.0 (the most up-to-date version) contain Property (I installed the vaadin-server.jar's and then looked inside each one).

I'm thinking about making a Vaadin 8 version of ExpandingTextArea.

As such, is there some alternative to Property in Vaadin 8 that I could use?

Comment: Looks like there is no Vaadin 8 version of the `ExpandingTextArea` addon...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm intending on making my own; I obtained the source code for the version for Vaadin 7 from https://vaadin.com/directory/component/expandingtextarea, so I would need to change it so that it used an alternative to Property - I just don't know what alternatives would be available to me.

Comment: This one is v8 compatible https://github.com/markusheikkinen/ExpandingTextArea